# Trouble understanding a simple shell script

Tags: linux, debugging, shell, gcc

I have not used shell scripting in ages. I have searched online for help but have not found adequate guides..

Here is the code I am trying to understand:

```
#!/bin/sh
# -*-sh-*-
if gcc $1 &> cmp_out; then
    if ! ./a.out &> run_out; then
        exit 0;                 # Success.
    fi
fi
exit 1;                         # Failure.
```

what is cmp_out, and run_out? Are these std_out?

I know that &> is a redirection instruction. But i do not get what that means in this scripts syntax in the slightest bit.

I am looking for a high level overview of what this script is doing. If you need more information about why i am using this script let me know. I will include more about the why.

In short it is an included example of delta debugging (//www.st.cs.uni-saarland.de/dd/)

Comment: `cmp_out` is the output from the compile, `run_out` is the output from running the resulting executable.

Comment: they are files output is being redirected to.

Comment: The logic is a bit funny: if a.out has a non-zero exit status, then that is success?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This script takes one argument, the name of a source file. It compiles that source file with `gcc` and if that compilation succeeds it executes the result. (By default, `gcc` writes the executable as a file named `a.out`.)

If the compilation fails, you're in luck, because the script saves the output (both standard output and standard error) into a file called `cmp_out`. And if the executed result produces any output, it saves that in `run_out`. The script itself writes nothing to stderr or stdout. Even if `gcc` isn't found, that error will end up in `cmp_out`.

The strangest thing about the script is that it inverts the exit status of the execution, using the exclamation point after the `if`. If executing `a.out` fails, the script exits with 0, success. If `a.out` succeeds, the script exits with 1, failure, which is also what it does if the compilation fails. Maybe the exclamation point is an error? The semicolon after the integers are unnecessary.

Comment: This is from a "Delta Debugging" package that is used in CS classes.  If an input causes failure, then it is considered a "successful" test case. http://delta.stage.tigris.org/using_delta.html

Answer (score 3):

`>` redirects the standard output of the preceding command to a named file.  `&>` redirects both standard output and standard error.

So `cmp_out` is a filename that will receive the standard output and standard error output from the compiler.  `run_out` receives the standard output and standard error from `a.out` (probably the binary that was built by the `gcc` command).

Answer (score 3):

There's also a bug in the program, in that the shorthand syntax of "&>" is a bash thing, and doesn't work in the regular sh shell.  It should be "#!/bin/bash" for the first line.